# Call a function in the value attribute of a readonly input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a registration form for a project and I need a randomly generated passcode. I have got a function that does this:

```
function getRandomPasscode() {
        min = 0;
        max = 10000000000;
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Then I have the inputs for the registration:

```
<form action="/register" method="post">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" />
        <label>Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" />
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input name="surname" type="text" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" />
        <label>Repeat Password</label>
        <input name="repeat_password" type="password" />
        <label>Passcode</label>
        <input name="passcode" type="text" value="getRandomPasscode()" readonly>
</form>
```

The aim is to have an input box for the passcode, which will contain the randomly generated passcode and will be readonly. The particular line:

```
<input name="passcode" type="text" value="getRandomPasscode()" readonly>
```

The function and the form are in one file and the function is defined before the form (not sure if this is necessary).

What should I write for the "value" attribute?

Comment: Don't put anything for a value, then add onFocus=getRandomPasscode()

Comment: Nothing. *Set* the value in the `getRandomPasscode` function and call it from `onsubmit` of the form.

Comment: Your submit button is missing in your shared codes, I would suggest that you create one more button such that it will trigger the javascript when clicked

Comment: Note that `label` elements should either wrap the text and the element, or have a `for` attribute that points to the `id` attribute of the element it labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set id for your password input and do not set value:

```
 <input id="passcode" name="passcode" type="text" readonly>
```

Below add script that sets password's value using your function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('passcode').value = getRandomPasscode();

    function getRandomPasscode() {
        min = 0;
        max = 10000000000;
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put anything in the value attribute, and then in the HTML I would add an onFocus attribute

```
     <input name="passcode" type="text" onFocus="getRandomPasscode()" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Insert passcode on page load:***

```js
function getRandomPasscode() {
  min = 0;
  max = 10000000000;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

document.getElementById("passcode").value = getRandomPasscode();
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="/register" method="post">
  <label>Passcode</label>
  <input id="passcode" name="passcode" type="text" readonly/>
  <label>Username</label>
  <input name="username" type="text" />
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" />
  <label>Surname</label>
  <input name="surname" type="text" />
  <label>Password</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" />
  <label>Repeat Password</label>
  <input name="repeat_password" type="password" />
</form>
```

***Insert passcode after clicking on 'Password' textbox:***

```js
function getRandomPasscode(elementId) {
  let min = 0,
  max = 10000000000,
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  document.getElementById(elementId).value = rand;
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p><b>Click in the 'Password' textbox</b></p>
<form action="/register" method="post">
  <label>Passcode</label>
  <input id="passcode" name="passcode" type="text" readonly/>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input name="password" type="password" onFocus="getRandomPasscode('passcode')" />
  <label>Repeat Password</label>
  <input name="repeat_password" type="password" />
  <label>Username</label>
  <input name="username" type="text" />
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="name" type="text" />
  <label>Surname</label>
  <input name="surname" type="text" />
</form>
```